# Chart.js - consolidating days to month totals along the x (time) axis?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm feeding two daily statistics datasets into my chart. As you can see, each element represents the value for a particular day.

```
"data":[[{"y":"1",  "x":"2018-04-01T04:00:00Z"},
         {"y":"14", "x":"2018-04-02T04:00:00Z"},
         {"y":"5",  "x":"2018-04-03T04:00:00Z"},
         {"y":"7",  "x":"2018-04-04T04:00:00Z"},
         ...
```

The x axis is defined as follows:

```
xAxes: [{
         type: 'time',
         distribution: 'series',
         time: {
                unit: 'month'
               }
        }]
```

I (naively?) thought that the chart would be rolling up (summing) the day values into the appropriate month buckets but that's not what I got. Instead, I got monthly tick marks along the x-axis but data points are plotted within the chart at daily precision. (See screenshot.)

Before I go ahead and reprocess my dataset to manually roll up days into their respective month buckets, I'd like to hear whether the chart can in fact do this for me but I'm just setting this up wrong, or whether I do in fact need to take care of this summarization myself, before supplying the dataset to the chart for plotting.

Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by doing the rollup myself during the assembly of the underlying dataset which is then supplied to the chart.

```
var dayDate = new Date($scope.insights.locationMetrics[lm].metricValues[metric].dimensionalValues[dim].timeDimension.timeRange.startTime);
var monthDate = dayDate.getFullYear() + "-" + (dayDate.getMonth() + 1);

var hitCount = {
    y: $scope.safeNumber($scope.insights.locationMetrics[lm].metricValues[metric].dimensionalValues[dim].value),
    x: monthDate
}
var alreadyRecorded = hits[labelIdx].findIndex(obj => obj.x == hitCount.x)

if (alreadyRecorded > -1) {
    hits[labelIdx][alreadyRecorded].y += Number(hitCount.y);
}
else {
    hits[labelIdx].push(hitCount);
}
```

1. Extract the date from the underlying data source
2. Extract yyyy-mm from the date
3. Create the hitCount object
4. Check if the hitCount object is already in the array
5. If the object is already in the array then increment the hitCount (y) within the array.
6. Otherwise, push the object into the array.

Comment: BTW - I've subsequently converted this 'time' chart to a 'line' chart. There's a bit of extra work to explicitly format the month labels for the x-axis but the upside is better, more explicit control over the x-axis.